# How to look up my games based on specific opening in lichess?

Tags: opening, lichess

This question is not related to chess as such and is more related to the chess website lichess. I tried asking in their forum but haven't yet got an answer.

I would like to look at **my** games based on a specific opening, say B20. The search doesn't allow me to search **my games based on a specific opening**.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot filter your own games based on a specific opening on lichess.

You can, however, aggregately analyze the results you achieved on a certain opening by exploiting the **Chess Insights** feature, which is available in your profile page (on the right-hand side of your rating graph).
After clicking on it and feeding your own games, you can go on the *Filters* tab, choose the specific opening you want under the *Game* window and then select the metrics you want to analyze. At the bottom there is also a set of games used to generate the insight.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of chess insights. Ideally, I would like to download my games I played in a specific opening. I think this is going to involve some work I guess.

Comment: @Adhvaitha You could download all your games from lichess, then import them in Chessbase.  From there, you can filter based on opening.

Comment: Other interfaces would also work- main advantages are that there are free options, but chessbase is quite pricey (about 100 USD). SCIDvsPC is my favorite, and it is capable of doing this.